# How to get right ldap resources with Zend Ldap?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ldap

I started using this module from Zend (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.ldap.introduction.html)  for work with LDAP, and I want to implement it into my classes which works with LDAP. But when I want to use some php ldap function which are not implemented in Zend-Ldap I have to get the **resource identifier** but I always get `resource(37) of type (Unknown)` or error `dap_mod_del(): 41 is not a valid ldap link resource (2)`. I think I use Zend module correctly you can see below.

Other zend-ldap features work perfect. But I cant get the right resources.

**index.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/api/AtaLdap.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/api/classes/Users.php';

$ldap = new AtaLdap\AtaLdap();
var_dump($ldap->Zend());
```

**AtaLdap.php**

```
namespace AtaLdap;

use Zend;

class AtaLdap
{

  const ldapServer = *********;
  const ldapPort = **********;
  const ldapLogin = *********;
  const ldapPass = *********;
  const ldapBaseDn = ********;

/**
 * Connect to LDAP via Zend LDAP module
 *
 * @return Zend\Ldap\Ldap
 * @throws Zend\Ldap\Exception\LdapException
 */
public static function Zend()
{
  $ldapOptions = [
    'host' => self::ldapServer,
    'port' => self::ldapPort,
    'password' => self::ldapPass,
    'bindRequiresDn' => TRUE,
    'baseDn' => self::ldapBaseDn,
    'username' => self::ldapLogin
  ];

  $ldap = new Zend\Ldap\Ldap($ldapOptions);
  $ldap->bind();

  return $ldap->getResource();
}

public static function ZendRes()
{
  return self::Zend()->getResource();
}

public static function deleteEntry($fromDN, $nameEntry, $contentEntry)
{
  $res = self::Zend()->getResource();
  $entryToDelete["$nameEntry"] = $contentEntry;
  $deleteEntry = ldap_mod_del($res, $fromDN, $entryToDelete);

  return $deleteEntry ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: what LDAP-server are you using as backend? Is it an AD or an OpenLDAP?

Comment: @heiglandreas It is Apacha AD

Comment: it works when I'm using it with procedural php

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! can you add some of the code that is not working so we can get an impression on how you are calling it?

Comment: @heiglandreas Added code where I need to use those resources

Comment: I think it could be faster to add this method to you code and use it from your module.

Comment: Yep, as I said. I added piece of my code to your (ldap.php) and it works. But    it should be done by you. I think several people wants to use `ldap_mod_del` and `ldap_mod_add` and it's not too complicated.

Comment: That's open as a feature request for quite a while now but no one implemented it yet. Do you want to give it a try? ;) As it's open source everyone is free (and welcome!) to contribute and fix things that are missing.

Comment: It's really good idea, I will do it asap